# how to increase Number of Count of Notification in android

Tags: android

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";
    String msg;
    String senderID;
    String recieverID;
    String parameter = "5";
    String time;
    private Handler handler;

    int count = 0;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        senderID = intent.getStringExtra("sender_id");
        recieverID = intent.getStringExtra("reccvier_id");
        // parameter = intent.getStringExtra("parameter");
        time = intent.getStringExtra("time");

        sendNotification(msg, senderID);

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg, String sender_id) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int params = 0;
        Intent myintent;

        if (parameter != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(parameter)) {
            params = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
        }

        if (params == 1) {
            myintent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
            myintent.putExtra("parmater", 2);
            myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
            myintent.putExtra("time", time);
        } else {
            myintent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
            myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
            myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
            myintent.putExtra("time", time);

        }
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lokii_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Locii Messge").setAutoCancel(true)
                .setNumber(count++)
                // .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://package_name/raw/sound"))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setNumber(++count).setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

here is my Screen : http://snag.gy/dUFrM.jpg

This code of Notification I getting Notification in Notification manger . But i am Unable show counter if they sent 5 notification and i didn't read notification .

I am trying using count=0 ;  in Notification builder count++ but i always set 1 while i am sending more than 1 notification My Notification message Updated  But Counter is not Increasing please suggest where i am doing wrong  .

Comment: as per my understanding when you will get more than 1 notification it will get override on each onther cause u used only one notification id in notify mehtod so you will get only one notification will be visible not all the notification will visible

Comment: ok But my Counter Increase by 2 when i sent notification 3 time then it show 6 Notifcation

Comment: i suggest saving it to `shared preferences`, then check if there is saved sharedpreferences then increment to count after that saved the current count which is from_save_preferences + 1, thats what i did.

Comment: As per ur current code for every notification the counter initialized with 0 . I f u want show the count, u have to store last value counter. Then every time u have to initialize ur counter value from the stored value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use static variable for count

```
static int count=0;
```

hope it will help you

```
    Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";
    String msg;
    String senderID;
    String recieverID;
    String parameter = "5";
    String time;
    private Handler handler;

    int count = 0;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        senderID = intent.getStringExtra("sender_id");
        recieverID = intent.getStringExtra("reccvier_id");
        // parameter = intent.getStringExtra("parameter");
        time = intent.getStringExtra("time");

        sendNotification(msg, senderID);

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg, String sender_id) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int params = 0;
        Intent myintent;

        if (parameter != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(parameter)) {
            params = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
        }

        if (params == 1) {
            myintent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
            myintent.putExtra("parmater", 2);
            myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
            myintent.putExtra("time", time);
        } else {
            myintent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
            myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
            myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
            myintent.putExtra("time", time);

        }
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lokii_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Locii Messge").setAutoCancel(true)
                // .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://package_name/raw/sound"))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setNumber(count).setContentText(msg);


        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(count, mBuilder.build());

 count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to i reset count back to zero after reading the notification?

Comment: First upon why do u want to set it to 0?

second if still you want you can get push notification clicked event on that event you can set it to 0 i.e COUNT=0;